# UK Visit Visa Family

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am working for a company in UAE and have a UAE residence visa as well, but I am living and working remotely from India since last month.
I have applied for UK standard visitor visa and have Biometrics next week. Can I show my UAE salary account and bank statement in UAE as financial evidence?
In addition, I will attach the NOC letter from my employer and Indian bank account with a statement to show FD and a good amount of balance.
Would they consider my UAE bank statements as proof that I have regular income? Do I need to mention this in the cover letter?

Comment: The standard advice given here is give them any details which (a) help explain your financial circumstances, (b) help explain why you are not likely to overstay, (c) always tell the truth.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the reply. Will they consider my UAE bank statements if I am applying the visa from India ?

Comment: What matters is whether the UAE account is in your name **and** you can access the funds. Will you be returning to reside in UAE or is the change to remote working in India permanent? What ties to UAE do you have now you’re not physically working there? What ties to India do you have? Being able to work remotely can be a red flag, coupled with having family in UK it could be a *big* red flag unless you can show a compelling reason to leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit

Comment: @Traveller Thanks for the reply.  yes, I have a UAE account with my Name and I can access the fund via net banking and ATM card. Yes I will come back to UAE since I have a UAE residence Visa and I will attach my marriage certificate since my wife is not traveling with  me .

Answer (score 2):

> Can I show my UAE salary account and bank statement in UAE as financial evidence?

Yes. What matters is demonstrating that the funds are available to you (the account is in your name and you can access the funds).

> Would they consider my UAE bank statements as proof that I have regular income?

Yes. Presumably you will also be providing pay slips to prove the source of your income.

> Do I need to mention this in the cover letter?

Yes, since your situation is not 100% straightforward. As commented by @mdewey the standard advice given here is give them any details which (a) help explain your financial circumstances, (b) help explain why you are not likely to overstay, (c) always tell the truth